# regarding to visual Basic Compiler in VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am getting these error in Visual Studio 2008

**Error 1:**

> A problem occurred while trying to set the "Resources" parameter for the IDE's in-process compiler. External component has thrown an exception.    AVAT

**Error 2:**

> "Vbc" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.
>   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Hosting.IVbcHostObject.EndInitialization()
>   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Vbc.InitializeHostCompiler(IVbcHostObject vbcHostObject)
>   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Vbc.InitializeHostObject()
>   at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute()
>   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskEngine.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(EngineProxy engineProxy, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, ITask task, Boolean& taskResult)  AVAT

**Error 3:**

> Visual Basic **compiler is unable to recover** from the following error: System Error &H80131198&
>   Save your work and restart Visual Studio.

Comment: That's META_E_STRINGSPACE_FULL, "No logical space left to create more user strings".  Sounds like a fried disk drive actually.  If you can't compile "Hello world" then you have a sick machine.  That needs a doctor, not a programmer.

Comment: have you face such type of problem,if yas then pls provide help else like other one ignore it..becasuse its not measurable by you.

Comment: I'll happily ignore it like everybody else.